# Python Grouping Transpose

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have my data in a pandas dataframe

```
out[1]:
    NAME     STORE      AMOUNT
0   GARY     GAP          20
1   GARY     GAP          10
2   GARY     KROGER       15
3   ASHLEY   FOREVER21    30
4   ASHLEY   KROGER       10
5   MARK     GAP          10
6   ROGER    KROGER       30
```

I'm trying to get grouping by name, sum their total amount spent, while also generating columns for each unique store in the dataframe.
Desired:

```
out[1]:
    NAME      GAP      KROGER     FOREVER21
0   GARY      30        15            0
1   ASHLEY    0         10            30
2   MARK      10        0             0
3   ROGER     0         30            0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='NAME', 
                    columns='STORE', 
                    values='AMOUNT', 
                    aggfunc='sum', 
                    fill_value=0)
print (df1)
STORE   FOREVER21  GAP  KROGER
NAME                          
ASHLEY         30    0      10
GARY            0   30      15
MARK            0   10       0
ROGER           0    0      30
```

Alternative solution with aggregating by `groupby` and `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['NAME','STORE'])['AMOUNT'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
STORE   FOREVER21  GAP  KROGER
NAME                          
ASHLEY         30    0      10
GARY            0   30      15
MARK            0   10       0
ROGER           0    0      30
```

Last if need column from index values and remove column and index names:

```
print (df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None))
     NAME  FOREVER21  GAP  KROGER
0  ASHLEY         30    0      10
1    GARY          0   30      15
2    MARK          0   10       0
3   ROGER          0    0      30
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response!